# How to do Bootstrap Gird Custom Post Type loop for Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a custom post type called 'portfolio' and am looking to create the loop in 2 columns and 3 columns and also using Advanced Custom Fields to upload an image but I'm not sure what to add to the following code to make it happen.

My Steps

First: I want to generate custom post type that is coming from the portfolio page.

Second: When the user uploads their previous projects to the portfolio page. I want to only loop 8 previous samples to the Homepage.

Third:  The 2 columns grid I want to only display the most previous post. But 3 columns grid I want to only display the less previous post. I'm doing the bootstrap 4 grid correctly.

[image]

Here's the code that currently doesn't work for me. When I upload the images to the Portfolio page doesn't appear on the homepage.

```
   <!-- recent work -->
    <div class="old-portfolio recent_work">
        <div class="container-fluid text-center">
            <div class="row">
              <?php
                  $alter_args = new WP_Query(array('numberposts' => 8,'orderby' => 'post_date','post_type' => 'portfolio','suppress_filters' => true ) );
                  if ( $alter_args->have_posts() ) : while ( $alter_args->have_posts() ) : $alter_args->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="portfolio-work col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
                    <a href="<?php the_field('portfolio_image'); ?>" data-lightbox="placeholder-image">
                        <img class="" src="<?php the_field('portfolio_image'); ?>"/>
                    </a>

                    <li class="portfolio-item">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="portfolio-work col-md-4">
                  <a href="<?php the_field('portfolio_image'); ?>" data-lightbox="placeholder-image">
                    <img class="" src="<?php the_field('portfolio_image'); ?>"/>
                  </a>

                  <li class="portfolio-item">
                     <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h>
                  </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- recent work -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start a counter (by setting a variable) at the beginning of the loop to assign a number to each item in the loop. You can do it by adding `$i == 0;` And at the end of the loop you need to increase that variable by one `$i++;` so that the number will change after each item. After doing this you can easily change the treatment of the items by writing an if/else statement within the loop. In your example you want to set the first 2 items to have `col-md-6` class and the rest to have `col-md-4` class so you add `<?php if($i < 2){echo "6";} else {echo "4";} ?>`

```
<?php
    $alter_args = new WP_Query(array('numberposts' => 8,'orderby' => 'post_date','post_type' => 'portfolio','suppress_filters' => true ) );
    if ( $alter_args->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php $i == 0; //Start a counter by setting a variable ?>
<?php while ( $alter_args->have_posts() ) : $alter_args->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="portfolio-work col-xs-12 col-md-<?php if($i < 2){echo "6";} else {echo "4";} //For the first 2 items in the loop echo 6 else echo 4 ?> col-lg-12">
        <a href="<?php the_field('portfolio_image'); ?>" data-lightbox="placeholder-image">
        <img class="" src="<?php the_field('portfolio_image'); ?>"/>
                </a>
                <li class="portfolio-item">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>
                <?php $i++; //this will increase the counter by 1 at the end of each item in the loop ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, you explain well!